# Jquery and a select menu, toggle just goes for a second then reverses

Tags: jquery, forms, select

Here is what I have:

```
$(function () {
$('#race_info').click(function () {
    var race = $("select").val();
    $('#' + race).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/heathen_scum/CxRJ6/

when i run it live on my site it starts to show the div but then the select jumps back to dwarf and hides the div again. on the jsfiddle it starts to load it asks for a post request which I am completely confused about. But can you help me so it will just show the div.

Comment: the anchor tag <a> is reloading the page. you can fix this by placing a # in the href attribute or possibly even returning false in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor tag is causing the page to refresh, stop the default event:

```
$(function () {
    $('#race_info').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var race = $("select").val();
        $('#' + race).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I just wish there was a way to see what was happening bit by bit...I'm just getting started and its still a bit overwhelming